# Как обезопасить сервер от запросов со сторонних ресурсов [React + Spring]

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

У меня есть сервер написанный на Spring (REST Api сервер) и сайт написанный на ReactJS. Теперь мне надо соединить данные два приложения  между собою. Это достаточно легко, но тут есть небольшая загвостка:

- Доступ к серверу может получить только приложение, которое работает с такого-то IP или находится на таком-то домене.
- Если бот/человек пытается получить данные с серверу не с моего сайта, то ему будет отправлено сообщение об отказе.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего реализовать данную вещь?

P.S. На сайте нет формы для авторизации!

---

Как вариант, я думаю использовать JWT-токен (One-time token). То есть открывается приложение на React, ему как-то выдается токен и когда это приложение отправляет запросы на сервер, то в запрос вставляется данный токен. Но я не могу ничего подобного найти в интернете

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Доступ к серверу может получить только приложение, которое работает с такого-то IP или находится на таком-то домене.
> Если бот/человек пытается получить данные с серверу не с моего сайта, то ему будет отправлено сообщение об отказе.
> ```

Посмотрите в сторону [nginx](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/). Требования выше идеально описывают его непосредственную работу.

Конфигурация nginx будет проста:

```
http {
  allow 186.135.0.108; # ip фронтенда
  deny all;

  server {
    server_name your.backend.com;
    # прочие конфигурации nginx
  }
}
```

Все, кто не внесены в инструкцию allow будут получать ошибку 403

Более подробно про механизм deny/allow в nginx можно прочесть [здесь](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html).

Comment: Я думаю над тем, чтобы использовать CORS

Comment: nginx тут тоже приходит на помощь - по ссылке https://michielkalkman.com/snippets/nginx-cors-open-configuration/ есть готовая конфигурация для включения в nginx CORS